# iframe jump to named link

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, fancybox-2

I have an iframe that has a source of `/website-policy#privacy` but when this loads the iframe stays at the top instead of jumping to the id.  Is there anyway **without** the use of js to make this go to the correct section?

At the moment I have had to use the following jQuery:

```
iframe.contents().find('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: iframe.contents().find('#privacy').position().top - 10 }, 1);
```

but this seems rather untidy and I don't want to have to do this each time I have an iframe with a hash-tag in the url

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tfQk/9/) of what is happening, as you can see the fancybox is opening up but not jumping to the heading "Jump here"

[This is my workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/5tfQk/10/) You may have to click the link twice for the fancybox to appear

Comment: Maybe this helps you (last answer is without js): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419072/iframe-src-reallylongpage-htmlbottom-doesnt-work

Comment: don't know how he got that to work - I have enough content below the anchor so it should have jumped to it but seems that the only way I can get the iframe to move to the link is by using javascript

Comment: Can you please post your html part, so i can try local?

Comment: @twain, I have added a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `iframe` `preload` setting in fancybox. If you set this option to `false`, it will work as expected:

```
$('a.fancy').fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    iframe: {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, that's the simple solution I was after!  Bounty is yours in 3 hours